# Can't post question on Stack Overflow. Says "this looks like spam"

Tags: bug, spam

I have been a long time user of Stack Overflow and have just today signed up to post a question. The question description is quite long, does not reference any outside sites, but when I go to post it, I get a message saying "This looks like spam".

All of the detail in my question is necessary for full understanding of the problem, so how do I get this question posted? I can send the question detail, or if your system saves the question before it is actually posted, then you can look at my only question entitled "SQL tricky query to update contact id".

I have made the following screenshots:

...

What do I need to do so I can post my question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the question details?

Comment: I am about to post links to 4 screenshots, just a sec...

Comment: Seems reasonable enough for the most part; I'd suggest trimming a bit of the fluffiness in the closing paragraph ("thx" and "still with me" and so forth) but that shouldn't be triggering spam. Maybe the lack of code formatting for those tables is hurting you.

Comment: Removing a little bit of fluff didn't help.  How would I "code format" the tables?

Thx

Comment: Haha, I'll simply post the screenshots.  Great idea...

Comment: Actually, will having simply links to the screenshots put some ppl off and maybe they will skip the question?

Comment: You might want to have a look at  http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Yes, we meant to [edit] them in the question here on meta!

Comment: I tried posting the entire SO question into this Meta question only to exceed posting limits by a few thousand characters!

Comment: Can a SO moderator look at my pending question and simply accept it??

Comment: There is no such thing "pending question" and moderator can't help you bypass spam filters

Comment: Thx for the edit rene.

Comment: So, I tried editing those links into my SO question, but need 10 rep pts.  I guess I need to go answer some questions first?

Comment: Ambulance chasing?  What does  that comment have to do with anything?

Comment: So, is it fair to say that SO validations are a bit too restrictive given the contents of my question are perfectly legit??

Comment: @Kershaw If i could make one critique of that post, it would be to be more up front with the problem. The first paragraph should summarize your problem very briefly to create a summary that will display on the question list and in search results.

Comment: @KevinB Done, thx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be very happy that you couldn't post that. I really don't think that question will be well received in its current form. It is way too broad and it tries to address two problems instead of one.

So first split your question into TWO separate ones.

The first one will be about the insert in the `tblInquiry` and the `contacts`. Something like this:

> I have the table tblInquiry
>
> ```
> id |  name | lots of other fields 
> --------------------------------
> 1  |  foo  |  blah
> ```
>
> I have the table tblCustomer
>
> ```
> id  | custname | lots of other fields
> -----------------------------------
> 101 | Bar      | blieb
> ```
>
> To update inquiry I want to execute the following query
>
> ```
> insert inquiry 
> select id, custame
> from customer 
> where awesome where clause
> ```
>
> This gives an error/ wrong data / performs bad.
>
> I have a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) prepared so you can try the query your self.
>
> What can I do to prevent the error/fetch the correct data/ improve performance?

A similar approach should be followed for the other issue. You can supply the background information about how you got into this problem as a link but it doesn't need to be in the question.

Make sure to read the [editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) topics in the [help] as it contains guidance on how all the editing features work.

Also revisit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specially all the linked material at the end of that help topic. For the code parts you might want to study [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I agree that the question really is 2 questions.  But the background info is necessary to understand the issue and how it got to be this way.  I will try to pare it down.

Comment: I understand you think it is relevant but do you think it makes any difference to the technical challenge if a developer, the son of the boss or your neighbor wrote that code/invented the datamodel?

Comment: True.  I am rethinking my question and will try to post it with its bare essentials and some proper formatting.

Comment: Yay, see cleaned up question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864545/sql-tricky-query-to-update-contact-id